# InvalidateRect background

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I make sure that when using `InvalidateRect()`, the white background does not appear, but remains transparent? I tried to make it transparent in `WM_ERASEBKGND`, but I didn't find the transparent RGB code.

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rc;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    if(Show)
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0, 0.1));
    else SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(123, 2, 13));
            
    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
}

case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
{
    Show = 1;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, 1);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    break;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have updated my code to this:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
{
    printf("q");
    return 0;
    break;
}

case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
{
    Show = 1;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, 1);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    break;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvSy5.jpg

Comment: Why are you using `BeginPaint()` in `WM_ERASEBKGND`? That is only valid to use in `WM_PAINT`, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) even says so. The `wParam` of `WM_ERASEBKGND` gives you the `HDC` you need to draw on. And there is no "transparent RGB code". If you want a transparent background, then simply don't draw any background at all, and then return non-zero so a default background won't be drawn.

Comment: thus image will not be destroyed

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to show your updated code after applying the fix I mentioned. What is your actual goal with this code? What result are you trying to achieve, and what result are you getting instead? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aCP8B5t,I need to hover over the button I have a picture, I want to do it this way: load 2 images, when hovering over the main hide, the second show. If you add return 0; to WM_ERASEBKGND (the code in the main question), nothing happens, even the cursor stops changing, and if you remove this case, then the background becomes white
as in the picture

Comment: According to the [WM_ERASEBKGND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd): An application should return nonzero if it erases the background; otherwise, it should return zero. So you need to return True. If possible, you can show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information to help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: with return 1; not working too, the image remains in place - nothing happens, but if the cursor changes when you hover, then after processing the WM_ERASEBKGND event, the cursor stops changing. If necessary, I can record everything on video

Comment: You can provide a sample to help us reproduce the problem.